# XSLT Порядок возврата элементов элементом xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

Использую XSLT версии 1.0. Нужно пройтись по всем элементам, непосредственно следующим на первом уровне внутри конкретного xml-тега. В связи с чем обратил внимание на элемент xsl:for-each. Не нашел в документации: может ли эта инструкция выбирать элементы в порядке, отличном от порядка следования вложенных в разбираемый тег элементов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать сортировку.

Допустим, имеется xml-документ:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>Vasya</name>
        <age>20</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Petya</name>
        <age>100</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Kolya</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

Элемент `sort` нужно вставить сразу же после `for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="people/person">
    <xsl:sort select="age" order="descending" data-type="number"></xsl:sort>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

В данном случае сортировка производится по элементу `age` (возраст) в убывающем порядке. Чтобы значение 100 корректно распознавалось как большее, чем 20 и 25, используется тип данных `number`.

Подробнее смотрите, например, [здесь](http://citforum.ru/internet/xslt/xslt10.shtml).

Comment: Александр, а если не используется элемент xsl:sort? Хочу обратить внимание, что нужна информация именно для версии 1.0.